# F#: Path error when trying to run simple F# program on VS Code

Tags: path, f#, visual-studio-code, ionide

I just installed Visual Studio Code on a different laptop and then proceeded to get the Ionide-fsharp extension. I then tried to run this simple piece of code:

```
open System

let rec factorial n =
    if n = 0
    then 1
    else n * factorial (n - 1)

factorial 5
```

But then I get this error and I can't seem to fix it:

```
 open: the term 'open' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
 function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling on the name, 
 of if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

It then proceeds to throw a bunch more nonsense at me and repeats the error above for every single line of code I have written afterwards. Please help.

Comment: you are trying to run the code in a Powershell terminal. Use FSI. So make sure F# itself is installed on the PC (.NET or mono, as well as .netcore).

Comment: @s952163 sorry, i don't know how to do that. can you walk me through it?

Comment: See the [Use F#](https://fsharp.org/) button for Windows/Linux install instructions. If you joing F# Slack channel someone might help you with step-by-step.